# Need to source .vimrc from within vim to achieve wanted effect (italic comments)

Tags: vim

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21077380/10686480) great answer when trying to have *italic* comments in vim, I encounter a strange behaviour: I have those three relevant lines inside my `.vimrc`:

`set t_ZH=^[[3m`
`set t_ZR=^[[23m`
`highlight Comment cterm=italic`

When I open a file with vim, comments are not displayed in italic. However, if I do `:highlight Comment cterm=italic` or even `:source ~/.vimrc`, I get italic comments. Any idea for possible reasons for this?

EDIT: Following the helpful answers, I solved the problem by replacing `highlight Comment cterm=italic` in my `.vimrc` with `autocmd VimEnter * :highlight Comment cterm=italic`.
[This](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-5/index.html) article about scripting vim was also helpful.

Comment: Your .vimrc commands are likely being overwritten by your colorscheme or a plugin. You could add them to an augroup event to trigger after all buffer load events.

Comment: @Conner That was my first guess, too. I don't load any colorscheme in my .vimrc and the only two plugins being loaded are `supertab` and `auto-pairs`. Commenting them doesn't change the output. Placing the italics settings at the bottom of vimrc doesn't change anyting. Also, if the italics settings are being overwritten, how is it possible that sourcing vimrc from within vim makes them take effect? Shouldn't they then also being overwritten?

Comment: What happens when you specify `vim -u /path/to/my/.vimrc` when starting vim?

Comment: Comments are upright, as before. Doing `:source ~/.vimrc` gives italic comments. All other settings in `.vimrc` seem to work right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have to be a  user installed plugin which overwrittes your setting.
It could also be a filetype plugin which comes with vim. These filetype specific things are loaded after your `.vimrc` so they overwrite your settings there. Sourcing your `.vimrc` afterwards will overwrite them again.

Enter the following command to see where your problem lies:

```
:verbose hi Comment
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! `:verbose hi Comment` pointed me to line 34 of `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim`. Changing `cterm=NONE` to `cterm=italic` there solved my problem!

Comment: Glad to help, but you should not do that. That's the default color file for every user on your system, and may get changed by updates.
Have a look at `:help after-directory` or `:h auto-command` or just look on this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375119/override-options-set-by-ftplugins-in-vim