# Neovim -- comments in italic

Tags: lua, neovim

In my `init.vim` configuration script for *"Vim"* I configure comments to be in italic like this ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494435/vimrc-make-comments-italic#answer-3494948)):

```
highlight Comment cterm=italic gui=italic
```

This does not work in `init.lua` for *"Neovim"*. How can I port this settings to Lua in order to use it in *"Neovim"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using neovim 0.9 here. What actually worked is the following:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Comment', { italic=true })
```

Comment: This could be better than my answer. Note that I had to also add `fg = #ffffff` to the array in order for this to work. It seems that it resets fg color of the comments to the default.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to derive my answer by looking ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/me35u9/lua_config_to_set_highlight/)). The answer is this:

```
vim.highlight.create('Comment', {cterm='italic', gui='italic'}, false)
```

Comment: Note that this has to be applied after the color theme!